# Python Cryptography - Data too long for key size

Tags: python, cryptography, key, encryption-asymmetric

I'm trying to encrypt my message using asymmetric encryption. I'm using SHA256 algorithm. The key size is `2048`. This is my code:-

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization, hashes

private_key = rsa.generate_private_key(
    public_exponent=65537,
    key_size=2048,
    backend=default_backend()
)

public_key = private_key.public_key()

# saving public key
pem = public_key.public_bytes(
    encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
    format=serialization.PublicFormat.SubjectPublicKeyInfo
)

with open('public_key.pem', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(pem)


# reading public key
with open("public_key.pem", "rb") as key_file:
        public_key = serialization.load_pem_public_key(
            key_file.read(),
            backend=default_backend()
        )


message = {
    '504201': '504346',
    '504293': '504306',
    '504299': '504273',
    'B.O': 'B.O',
    'Non-Delivery': 'Delivery',
    'regionname': 'Hyderabad',
    'Sirpur (t)': 'Asifabad',
    'ANDHRA PRADESH\nAnnaram B.O': 'ANDHRA PRADESH\nChichdhari Khanapur B.O',
    'officeType': 'S.O',
    'Nirmal': 'Adilabad',
    'circlename': 'Andhra Pradesh',
    'Districtname': 'Adilabad',
    'ANDHRA PRADESH\nBansapalli B.O': 'ANDHRA PRADESH\nDeepaiguda B.O',
    'pincode': '504103',
    'ANDHRA PRADESH\nAndugulpet B.O': 'ANDHRA PRADESH\nBurguda B.O',
    '504202': '504313',
    '504231': '504293',
    'Hyderabad': 'Hyderabad',
    'Khanapur': 'Utnoor',
    'Luxettipet': 'Asifabad',
    'officename': 'dilabad)',
    'ANDHRA PRADESH\nBellalbadi B.O': 'ANDHRA PRADESH\nDhaboli B.O',
    'Taluk': 'Mudhole',
    'ANDHRA PRADESH\nBambara B.O': 'ANDHRA PRADESH\nCoal Chemical Complex S.O',
    'ANDHRA PRADESH\nBangalpet B.O': 'ANDHRA PRADESH\nDantanpalli B.O',
    'salt': 1,
    'divisionname': 'Adilabad',
    'statename\nAda B.O': 'ANDHRA PRADESH\nBirvelli B.O',
    'Delivery': 'Delivery',
    'ANDHRA PRADESH\nBhainsa S.O (A': 'ANDHRA PRADESH\nDhann',
    '504106': '504311',
    'Andhra Pradesh': 'Andhra Pradesh',
    'ANDHRA PRADESH\nArli (T) B.O': 'ANDHRA PRADESH\nChintaguda B.O',
    '504295': '504302',
    'Asifabad': 'Mancherial',
    'ANDHRA PRADESH\nBejjur B.O': 'ANDHRA PRADESH\nDehgaon B.O',
    '504306': '504309',
    '504312': '504296',
    'Adilabad': 'Adilabad',
    'Deliverystatus': 'Delivery',
    'Chennur': 'Utnoor'
}

message = json.dumps(message).encode('utf-8')


encrypted = self.public_key.encrypt(
                message,
                padding.OAEP(
                    mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256()),
                    algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
                    label=None
                )
            )
```

The above code raise an exception `ValueError: Data too long for key size. Encrypt less data or use a larger key size.` If I increase the key_size to 4096 it works. However, if my data has more keys, even 4096 fails.

As a workaround, I read multiple similar SO questions where it was advised to shorten(encrypt) the data using symmetric encryption, then use asymmetric.

I tried the same approach as follow:-

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
key = Fernet.generate_key()
cipher_suite = Fernet(key)
cipher_text = cipher_suite.encrypt(MY_ABOVE_JSON_DUMPS_MESSAGE)
encrypted = self.public_key.encrypt(
                cipher_text,
                padding.OAEP(
                    mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256()),
                    algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
                    label=None
                )
            )
```

This also results in same error, as the `cipher_text` is again too long.

How do I get it right?

Comment: Paul has already given the right answer, but I'll put some more focus on the fact that you need to **encrypt the AES key** rather than the ciphertext. Encryption is not compression; it won't shrink the message (the data you're encrypting). The reason why a  **hybrid cryptosystem** works is because you first protect the data with a random AES key, which you then in turn protect using the RSA public key.

Answer (score 6):

The nature of the RSA cryptosystem is such that you cannot encrypt a value longer than the modulus (and, in fact, it must shorter to be able to encrypt it safely as RSA's security is partially premised on padding).

If you want to encrypt a larger payload you need to instead construct a system such that you encrypt your payload using a symmetric cipher (make sure it's authenticated encryption! `cryptography` provides a construction called Fernet that can do this), and then encrypt the symmetric key using your RSA public key. You can then send both ciphertexts over to the recipient. The recipient can decrypt the RSA encrypted key using the private key they hold and decrypt the larger ciphertext with the resulting key.

If you are building this system from scratch consider using [PyNaCl](https://github.com/pyca/pynacl)'s `Box`, but if you need more popular cryptographic primitives then a concept like [ECIES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Encryption_Scheme) can also achieve this sort of ability without using RSA.

Answer (score 0):

Asymmetric Cryptography is a slow cryptographic technique, You should use AES or equivalent to do it, If you still want to achieve Public Key Cryptography. Encrypt the data using AES: Create an object with Header as AES key and AES Encrypted Data as payload... Only encrypt AES key using PKC.

Answer (score -6):

Try to shorten your message using a hash alg. like sha256. Then try to encrypt the message

Comment: I'm using asymmetric cryptography. If I use SHA family, I won't be able to decrypt it later.

Comment: Then you can use RSA functions, too encrypt and decyrpt